# MATLAB matrix power algorithm

Tags: python, matlab, scipy, matrix-multiplication

I'm looking to port an algorithm from MATLAB to Python. One step in said algorithm involves taking `A^(-1/2)` where A is a 9x9 square complex matrix. As I understand it, the square root of matrices (and by extension their inverses) are not-unique.

I've been experimenting with `scipy.linalg.fractional_matrix_power` and an approximation using `A^(-1/2) = exp((-1/2)*log(A))` with numpy's built in `expm` and `logm` functions. The former is exceptionally poor and only provides 3 decimal places of precision whereas the latter is decently correct for elements in the top left corner but gets progressively worse as you move down and to the right. This may or may not be a perfectly valid mathematical solution to the expression however it doesn't suffice for this application.

As a result, I'm looking to directly implement MATLAB's matrix power algorithm in Python so that I can 100% confirm the same result each time. Does anyone have any insight or documentation on how this would work? The more parallelizable this algorithm is, the better, as eventually the goal would be to rewrite it in OpenCL for GPU acceleration.

EDIT: An MCVE as requested:

```
[[(0.591557294607941+4.33680868994202e-19j), (-0.219707725574605-0.35810724986609j), (-0.121305654177909+0.244558388829046j), (0.155552026648172-0.0180264818714123j), (-0.0537690384136066-0.0630740244116577j), (-0.0107526931263697+0.0397896274845627j), (0.0182892503609312-0.00653264433724856j), (-0.00710188853532244-0.0050445035279044j), (-2.20414002823034e-05+0.00373184532662288j)], [(-0.219707725574605+0.35810724986609j), (0.312038814492119+2.16840434497101e-19j), (-0.109433401402399-0.174379997015402j), (-0.0503362231078033+0.108510948023091j), (0.0631826956936223-0.00992931123813742j), (-0.0219902325360141-0.0233215237172002j), (-0.00314837555001163+0.0148621558916679j), (0.00630295247506065-0.00266790359447072j), (-0.00249343102520442-0.00156160619280611j)], [(-0.121305654177909-0.244558388829046j), (-0.109433401402399+0.174379997015402j), (0.136649392858215-1.76182853028894e-19j), (-0.0434623984527311-0.0669251299161109j), (-0.0168737559719828+0.0393768358149159j), (0.0211288536117387-0.00417146769324491j), (-0.00734306979471257-0.00712443264825166j), (-0.000742681625102133+0.00455752452374196j), (0.00179068247786595-0.000862706240042082j)], [(0.155552026648172+0.0180264818714123j), (-0.0503362231078033-0.108510948023091j), (-0.0434623984527311+0.0669251299161109j), (0.0467980890488569+5.14996031930615e-19j), (-0.0140208255975664-0.0209483313237692j), (-0.00472995448413803+0.0117916398375124j), (0.00589653974090387-0.00134198920550751j), (-0.00202109265416585-0.00184021636458858j), (-0.000150793859056431+0.00116822322464066j)], [(-0.0537690384136066+0.0630740244116577j), (0.0631826956936223+0.00992931123813742j), (-0.0168737559719828-0.0393768358149159j), (-0.0140208255975664+0.0209483313237692j), (0.0136137125669776-2.03287907341032e-20j), (-0.00387854073283377-0.0056769786724813j), (-0.0011741038702424+0.00306007798625676j), (0.00144000687517355-0.000355251914809693j), (-0.000481433965262789-0.00042129815655098j)], [(-0.0107526931263697-0.0397896274845627j), (-0.0219902325360141+0.0233215237172002j), (0.0211288536117387+0.00417146769324491j), (-0.00472995448413803-0.0117916398375124j), (-0.00387854073283377+0.0056769786724813j), (0.00347771689075251+8.21621958836671e-20j), (-0.000944046302699304-0.00136521328407881j), (-0.00026318475762475+0.000704212317211994j), (0.00031422288569727-8.10033316327328e-05j)], [(0.0182892503609312+0.00653264433724856j), (-0.00314837555001163-0.0148621558916679j), (-0.00734306979471257+0.00712443264825166j), (0.00589653974090387+0.00134198920550751j), (-0.0011741038702424-0.00306007798625676j), (-0.000944046302699304+0.00136521328407881j), (0.000792908166233942-7.41153828847513e-21j), (-0.00020531962049495-0.000294952695922854j), (-5.36226164765808e-05+0.000145645628243286j)], [(-0.00710188853532244+0.00504450352790439j), (0.00630295247506065+0.00266790359447072j), (-0.000742681625102133-0.00455752452374196j), (-0.00202109265416585+0.00184021636458858j), (0.00144000687517355+0.000355251914809693j), (-0.00026318475762475-0.000704212317211994j), (-0.00020531962049495+0.000294952695922854j), (0.000162971629601464-5.39321759384574e-22j), (-4.03304806590714e-05-5.77159110863666e-05j)], [(-2.20414002823034e-05-0.00373184532662288j), (-0.00249343102520442+0.00156160619280611j), (0.00179068247786595+0.000862706240042082j), (-0.000150793859056431-0.00116822322464066j), (-0.000481433965262789+0.00042129815655098j), (0.00031422288569727+8.10033316327328e-05j), (-5.36226164765808e-05-0.000145645628243286j), (-4.03304806590714e-05+5.77159110863666e-05j), (3.04302590501313e-05-4.10281583826302e-22j)]]
```

Comment: What do you mean by "3 decimal places of precision"? Is your issue a difference between the matlab and the numpy result? As long as both matrices produce `B^2==A`, both are valid results. Your application should either not rely on any uniqueness (when there's none), or give an additional constraint that makes the answer unique.

Comment: As in I will run `scipy.linalg.fractional_matrix_power(A,(-1/2))` and get some elements that are like (-8.50000000e+01 - 1.65625000e+02j) and there's no reason for that first answer to be exactly 85. 

The issue in the application is that this algorithm gets iterated upon such that a later result converges. I've tested my python ports to over 1000 iterations and they still carry errors of 10% or so in some cases.

Comment: [Here](https://nickhigham.wordpress.com/2016/04/05/improved-matlab-function-sqrtm) is a good review.

Answer (score 0):

I can think of two explanations, in both cases I accuse user error. In chronological order:

### Theory #1 (the subtle one)

My suspicion is that you're copying the *printed* values of the input matrix from one code as input into the other. I.e. you're throwing away double precision when you switch codes, which gets amplified during the inverse-square-root calculation.

As proof, I compared MATLAB's inverse square root with the very function you're using in python. I will show a 3x3 example due to size considerations, but—spoiler warning—I did the same with a 9x9 random matrix and got two results with condition number `11.245754109790719` (MATLAB) and `11.245754109790818` (numpy). That should tell you something about the similarity of the results without having to save and load the actual matrices between the two codes. I suggest you do this though: keywords are [`scipy.io.loadmat`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.19.0/reference/generated/scipy.io.loadmat.html) and [`savemat`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.19.0/reference/generated/scipy.io.savemat.html).

What I did was generate the random data in python (because that's what I prefer):

```py
>>> import numpy as np
>>> print((np.random.rand(3,3) + 1j*np.random.rand(3,3)).tolist())
[[(0.8404782758300281+0.29389006737780765j), (0.741574080512219+0.7944606900644321j), (0.12788250870304718+0.37304665786925073j)], [(0.8583402784463595+0.13952117266781894j), (0.2138809231406249+0.6233427148017449j), (0.7276466404131303+0.6480559739625379j)], [(0.1784816129006297+0.72452362541158j), (0.2870462766764591+0.8891190037142521j), (0.0980355896905617+0.03022344706473823j)]]
```

By copying the same truncated output into *both* codes, I guarantee the correspondence of the inputs.

Example in MATLAB:

```matlab
>> M = [[(0.8404782758300281+0.29389006737780765j), (0.741574080512219+0.7944606900644321j), (0.12788250870304718+0.37304665786925073j)]; [(0.8583402784463595+0.13952117266781894j), (0.2138809231406249+0.6233427148017449j), (0.7276466404131303+0.6480559739625379j)]; [(0.1784816129006297+0.72452362541158j), (0.2870462766764591+0.8891190037142521j), (0.0980355896905617+0.03022344706473823j)]];
>> A = M^(-0.5);
>> format long
>> disp(A)
  0.922112307438377 + 0.919346397931976i  0.108620882045523 - 0.649850434897895i -0.778737740194425 - 0.320654127149988i
 -0.423384022626231 - 0.842737730824859i  0.592015668030645 + 0.661682656423866i  0.529361991464903 - 0.388343838121371i
 -0.550789874427422 + 0.021129515921025i  0.472026152514446 - 0.502143106675176i  0.942976466768961 + 0.141839849623673i

>> cond(A)

ans =

   3.429368520364765
```

Example in python:

```py
>>> M = [[(0.8404782758300281+0.29389006737780765j), (0.741574080512219+0.7944606900644321j), (0.12788250870304718+0.37304665786925073j)], [(0.8583402784463595+0.13952117266781894j), (0.2138809231406249+0.6233427148017449j), (0.7276466404
... 131303+0.6480559739625379j)], [(0.1784816129006297+0.72452362541158j), (0.2870462766764591+0.8891190037142521j), (0.0980355896905617+0.03022344706473823j)]]

>>> A = fractional_matrix_power(M,-0.5)

>>> print(A)
[[ 0.92211231+0.9193464j   0.10862088-0.64985043j -0.77873774-0.32065413j]
 [-0.42338402-0.84273773j  0.59201567+0.66168266j  0.52936199-0.38834384j]
 [-0.55078987+0.02112952j  0.47202615-0.50214311j  0.94297647+0.14183985j]]

>>> np.linalg.cond(A)
3.4293685203647408
```

My suspicion is that if you `scipy.io.loadmat` the matrix into python, do the calculation, `scipy.io.savemat` the result and load it back in with MATLAB, you'll see less than `1e-12` absolute error (hopefully even less) between the results.

---

### Theory #2 (the facepalm one)

My suspicion is that you're using python 2, and your `-1/2`-powered division is a simple inverse:

```py
>>> # python 3 below
>>> # python 3's // is python 2's /, i.e. integer division
>>> 1/2
0.5
>>> 1//2
0
>>> -1/2
-0.5
>>> -1//2
-1
```

So if you're using python 2, then calling

```
fractional_matrix_power(M,-1/2)
```

is actually the inverse of `M`. The obvious solution is to switch to python 3. The less obvious solution is to keep using python 2 (which you shouldn't, as the above exemplifies), but use

```
from __future__ import division
```

on top of your every source file. This will override the behaviour of the simple `/` division operator so that it reflects the python 3 version, and you will have one less headache.

Comment: To start, I'm not actually importing data from MATLAB. The original algorithm exists as MATLAB code and I'm attempting to recreate it in python from scratch. Both are reading from the same data files.

All other steps prior to this (including some of the complicated broadcasted operations we've discussed in the past) maintain exactly identical answers.

I've confirmed that `fractional_matrix_power` doesn't work on my end with -0.5 but is better with 0.5 and then taking the inverse. This result gets closer to the `expm(-0.5*logm(A))` approximation. However it is still up to 10% incorrect.

Comment: I'm also using 3.5.2

Comment: @Mike what might be relevant is the numpy/scipy version; I'll tell you mine when I'm in front of my laptop. In the mean time, make sure that the difference is not due to slight differences in the computed input, i.e. do the above test with a surely identical matrix if you haven't done so far. And how singular/ill-conditioned are your matrices? If a smaller submatrix reproduces your issue, you should add it to your question for cross-checking (both programs).

Comment: I'm running numpy 1.11.1 and scipy 0.17.1

The conditional number from MATLAB is 11115584961.2. The conditional number from python is 1894696172.73. So my guess is very ill-conditioned if I'm understanding this metric correctly.

Comment: Numpy 1.12.0 and scipy 0.18.1. here. But there's your problem: those condition numbers are ***huge***. Are your determinants close to 0 too? Highly likely). The bottom line is probably that negative powers of such a matrix are very sensitive to rounding and other kinds of errors. Unless there's some underlying heuristic in either of the programs that handles ill-conditioned cases separately.